# How to create two Aerospike Clusters on same L2 network

Tags: redhat, iptables, subnet, aerospike, aerospike-loader

I am using two aerospike clusters(each with one node/machine only).

Since both machine are on same LAN, they try to connect each other trying to form single cluster. Because of this I was getting error(while inserting record):

```
Error: (11) AEROSPIKE_ERR_CLUSTER
```

So on my ubuntu setup(one of two machines) I blocked port 9918 using cmd:

```
ufw block 9918
```

After block cmd, aerospike clusters started working(I was able to insert record).

Whats better way to avoid two Aerospike machines on same LAN to not communicate with each other ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just make sure to change the multicast address and/or port in the heartbeat configuration so the 2 nodes don't try to send heartbeat to each other.

`heartbeat {
    mode multicast                  # Send heartbeats using Multicast
    address 239.1.99.2              # multicast address
    port 9918                       # multicast port
    interval 150                    # Number of milliseconds between heartbeats
    timeout 10                      # Number of heartbeat intervals to wait
                                    # before timing out a node
  }`

Alternatively, you can also switch to mode mesh and have only the node itself in the mesh-see-address-port list:

`heartbeat {
    mode mesh                   # Send heartbeats using Mesh (Unicast) protocol
    port 3002                   # port on which this node is listening to
                                # heartbeat
    mesh-seed-address-port 192.168.1.100 3002 # IP address for seed node in the cluster
                                              # This IP happens to be the local node
    interval 150                # Number of milliseconds between heartbeats
    timeout 10                  # Number of heartbeat intervals to wait before
                                # timing out a node
  }`

Comment: U mean I should change multicast address in one of two machines to some other multicast address ?

Comment: Yes, to make sure they don't send heartbeat to each other. You could also switch to mode mesh and only have the node itself in the mesh-see-address-port. I will add an example in my response above.